# scrollspy in flask bootstrap not working (Jinja2)

Tags: javascript, python, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying all the fixes available here in SO, but it hasn't solved my problem yet.

Here's my current code (HTML):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
<body class="scroll-area" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#spy" data-offset="0">
{% block navbar %}
<div >
        <div  id="spy" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#section1">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#section2">Who Am I</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section3">What I Can Do For You</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section4">Contact Me</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Testing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

javascript part:

```
{% block script %}
{{super()}}
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas appreciated :)

Update:

I've tried using a plain version (all pure html, css and js) and it works fine.
The bug might have something to do on Flask's Jinja2 templating.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this issue as well.
It appears the navbar-fixed-top example from bootstrap uses an extra css file "navbar-fixed-top.css", just check the source in the example. This is missing in the flask bootstrap base.html template. I was looking for the import that might provide it, but didn't see it. I just added a 'custom' css file to my flask_bootstrap template like this :

```
{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('.static', filename='css/navbar-fixed-top.css')}}">
{% endblock %}
```

Put the contents of the bootstrap example in that file and it should work. The bootstrap example points to this file : http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/navbar-fixed-top.css.

Hope that helps.